# Compute target points from tracked features with optical flow

Tags: opencv, surf, opticalflow

I need to accurately track 9 points around the eyes. I detect the face & eyes and compute the points (center of the eyes, etc). As these points are not good features to track (they are lost quite quickly by optical flow), I also extract features from the face region (SURF/goodFeaturesToTrack) and I use those with KLT. My goal is to determine those 9 interest points from the other tracked ones / recover lost points from the initial 9 using the other tracked points. My initial thought was that I could compute the displacement with optical flow and use that for the target points, but I didn't get good results (tried with the average of the displacement, which is obviously incorrect). My question is: is something like this doable at all ? And if it is, how should I relate the target points to the tracked features so that I can obtain them again in subsequent frames ?

Answer (score 0):

in your tracking instead of tracking single pixels you can create a region around each pixels
if p1 is the point you are tracking create a region using surrounding pixels and choose good features to track and track all those feature points.after tracking calculate average motion for p1 from these tracked points.if some points are lost in that region you can easily construct the surrounding points for next iteration tracking.

in this type the probability of losing points is low.lost point reconstruction is very easy.